# How to check duplicate number range element in JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For example,

```
[{
    "numberStart": "300",
    "numberEnd": "350",
    "id": "1"
}, {
    "numberStart": "351",
    "numberEnd": "400",
    "id": "2"
}, {
    "numberStart": "380", 
    "numberEnd": "400",
    "id": "3"
}]
```

In the above example, the third element of the array is duplicate because numberStart and numberEnd ranges already exist in the 2nd element of the array. How to find the duplicate element?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service where you drop in your requirements and get out ready to use code. What have you tried yourself to solve your problem?

Comment: But for starters, i'd begin with converting the `numberStart` and `numberEnd` properties to be of type `number` not `string` ...

Comment: @joshi098 Do you wish to remove the 3rd element that already exists?

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei : I would like to find the duplicate element whenever it inserts a new object in the array?

Comment: @joshi098 Hope my answer can give you an idea or be of help.

Comment: @joshi098 u are most welcome. Unfair for people down voting ur question as it is a valid question. See my other questions and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you start with an empty list and you keep adding objects range to it.

One possible solution is the following. The new objects will be added only if they do not overlap the max range of the existing elements.

In the example below only the objects 1, 2, and 5 will be added to the array.

```js
let list = [];   // start with an empty list
//--------------------------------
function addToList(list , toAdd) {
const maxValue = Math.max(...list.map(o => o.numberEnd), 0);
if (toAdd.numberEnd > maxValue) list=[{...list,...toAdd}];
return list;
}
//--------------------------------

list = addToList(list,{"numberStart": 300,"numberEnd": 350, "id": "1"});  // will be added
list = addToList(list,{"numberStart": 351,"numberEnd": 400, "id": "2"});  // will be added
list = addToList(list,{"numberStart": 380, "numberEnd": 400, "id": "3"}); // it will not be added
list = addToList(list,{"numberStart": 200, "numberEnd": 300, "id": "4"}); // it will not be added
list = addToList(list,{"numberStart": 401, "numberEnd": 500, "id": "5"}); // will be added

console.log(list);
```